# Does IntelliJ GWT studio plugin support Hotswap of GWT client side classes?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, gxt

I am working on a project using GXT. When I use Eclipse as the development environment, I see that the client side classes are being hot swapped.

For example, if there was a button pressing which would render a "new" `customWidget` built using the `LayoutContainer` in GXT, any changes made to this `customWidget` would be hotswapped. Meaning, I need not refresh the browser everytime to see the changes I made. Since a new `customWidget` is rendered everytime, I would see the changes right away with out refresh.

In IntelliJ however, this hot swap is not happening. I am being forced to do a full refresh of the page and thereby, losing the state of the application. I have to perform all the steps again to get to the previous state before I can test the change.

It definetely makes sense if I have made changes to something that has already been rendered and thus needs a refresh. But for something that has not been rendered yet, Eclipse hotswaps the code.

Please let me know if I need to change any settings that will make IntelliJ behave the same as Eclipse for GWT programming.

Comment: Still not happening in 2016, probably never will... But according to the official doc this hotswap is not reliable and we should do the refresh anyway